# Using threads to modify an object

Tags: java, java-threads

I'm new to threads. I wanted to get two threads to increment an integer to a certain value. because int type is immutable, I switched to atomic integer. I also tried to wrap an int to a class and that didn't work either. I also tried static/volatile int and that didn't work. I also tried to use fairness policy. The main issue is that "counterObj" is not incremented correctly and is still set to 0 even though it is injected to both threads.

My expected running behavior:

```
thread       value
thread 0     0
thread 1     1
thread 0     2
...
```

What I wrote so far:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        try {
            app.launch();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void launch() throws InterruptedException {
        int increments = 100;
        AtomicInteger counterObj = new AtomicInteger(0);
        CounterThread th1 = new CounterThread("1", counterObj, increments);
        CounterThread th2 = new CounterThread("2", counterObj, increments);
        th1.start();
        th2.start();


        System.out.println(counterObj.get());

    }


}
```

and

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class CounterThread implements Runnable {
    private final String threadID;
    private AtomicInteger counterObj;
    private int bound;

    public CounterThread(String threadID, AtomicInteger counter, int bound) {
        this.threadID = threadID;
        this.counterObj = counter;
        this.bound = bound;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (counterObj.get() < bound) {
            synchronized (this) {
                counterObj.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadID + " finished");
    }


    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this, threadID);
        thread.join();
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Just for the record: calling your class counterThread to then make it *implement* Runable, but internally create a Thread object itself ... that is a really weird design. It adds a ton of confusion to your code, without any need to do so. Make the class extend thread itself, or give it a different name, that better describes what it is doing.

Comment: and the start method also... I think the control of the thread should be in the main (calling join() and start)...

Comment: You have `synchronized` method in `CounterThread` class which means that each object of that class will have its own lock and will not prevent other objects of `CounterThread` class to execute method.

Comment: Don't synchronize run, and don't do the synchronize(this) inside of a synchronized method. You need to synchronize on a shared object to be of any use.

Comment: The whole point of `AtomicInteger` is that it enforces atomicity itself. You don't *need* to do your own synchronization around `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` because the class guarantees it'll do it atomically itself.

Comment: Your actual problem is that you don't wait for your two threads to complete before your `println()`

Comment: @slim I think they're trying a double check, in which case you might want to synchronize on the integer.

Comment: You shouldn't call join before you call start. I think that is where youre program is sticking.

Comment: @matt but there's no point in double-checking. The first check is reliable.

Comment: @slim In ops code it is broken, I put an answer with the double check. In my example, without the synchronized 'i' could be 2, then Thread a and b enter the while loop, and they'll both increment and bounds could be 4 at the end.

Comment: @matt Ah, I admit I hadn't looked at the `while(i.get()...)`. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your program is exiting before your threads get a chance to do anything (probably due to the ordering of your starts and joins.  I would move your thread starting logic into your main(or launch) method.  Something like the following.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyCounterRunnable("1", counterObj, increments));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyCounterRunnable("2", counterObj, increments));
```

Then, in your main, you need to call join *after* starting the threads...as follows:

```
thread1.start(); // starts first thread.
thread2.start(); // starts second thread.

thread1.join(); // don't let main exit until thread 1 is done.
thread2.join(); // don't let main exit until thread 2 is done.
```

Comment: Other changes I would make.  1. synchronize on counterObj (instead of 'this').  2. Remove the synchronized modifier from the 'public void run' method.

Comment: These good advices - add them to the answer rather than getting them lost in the comment. By the way, there is no need for synchronised block - `AtomicInteger` takes care of the synchronisation.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I removed the modifier and moved the start and join logic into main. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you really are wanting is for only one thread to increment an int at a time. 
The int variable is the resource you want in the synchronized block, so the different threads can increment it one at a time.
This can be done using syncrhonize alone.
Disclaimer: I didn't run the code so it could have some typo or Exceptions to be removed from the Application class.

```
public class Application {

  private int theVar = 0;
  private int increments = 100;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application app = new Application();
    try {
        app.launch();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public synchronized addOne(){
    this.theVar++;
  }

  private void launch() throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable counter1 = new Counter(this, increments), counter2 = new Counter(this, increments);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(counter1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(counter2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

A counter class

```
public class Counter implements Runnable{
  private Application app;
  int rounds = -1;

  public Counter(Application app, rounds){
    this.app = app;
    this.rounds = rounds;
  }
  public void run(){
    while(int i=0; i<rounds; i++){
        this.app.addOne();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've included a double check on the AtomicInteger, this appears to be what you've been trying to accomplish.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class DualCounters{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        int bounds = 3;

        Thread a = new Thread(()->{
            int last = 0;
            while(i.get()<bounds){
                synchronized(i){
                    if(i.get()<bounds){
                        last = i.getAndIncrement();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("a last " + last);
        });

        Thread b = new Thread(()->{
            int last = 0;
            while(i.get()<bounds){
                synchronized(i){
                    if(i.get()<bounds){
                        last = i.getAndIncrement();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("b last " + last);
        });

        a.start();
        b.start();

        a.join();
        b.join();

        System.out.println(i.get() + " afterwards");

    }
}
```

The double check is a broken concept in java, the AtomicInteger offers tools for accomplishing this without any synchronization.

```
int a;
while((a = i.getAndIncrement())<bounds){
    ...
}
```

Now a will never be greater than bounds *inside of the while loop*. When the loop is finished `i` and `a` could have a value greater than bounds.

If that was an issue, there is always the other method `getAndUpdate`

```
while((a = i.getAndUpdate(i->i<bounds?i+1:i)<bounds){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AtomicInteger` takes care of atomicity itself, so you shouldn't need to use `synchronized` -- but only if you play by the rules, and do your atomic operations in one call.

You're failing to do this, because you call `counterObj.get()` then depending on the result `counterObj.incrementAndGet()`. You need to avoid this because you want the check and the update to be part of the same atomic chunk of work.

You can get close with:

```
while(counterObj.incrementAndGet() < bound) {} ;
```

But this will always increment at least once, which may be once too many.

Slightly more involved:

```
IntUnaryOperator incrementWithLimit = x -> 
   ( x < bound ? x + 1 : x );

while(counterObj.updateAndGet(incrementWithLimit) < bound) {};
```

That is, we've created a function that increments a number only if it's lower than `bound`, and we tell `AtomicInteger` to apply that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

[Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) method works only if the thread has started, else it does nothing. So you must reorder your code, but if you just move the **join** method after **start**, when starting the first thread by calling **CounterThread.start**, the main thread will wait until the started thread has finished, blocked in the **Thread.join** method, and only then will continue to starting the second one. A solution is to make an additional method in the **CounterThread** class, that will be called after both threads have been started:

```
public void waitFinish() throws InterruptedException {
    thread.join();
}
```

**synchronized (this)** is synchronizing on the **CounterThread** instance that has been created when you called **new CounterThread(...)**, but you have two instances so each will be synchronizing on a different object. For synchronized to work, you need to use a common instance of an object, in this case you can use the shared **counterObj**.

Only the **AtomicInteger** methods are guaranteed to be thread safe, so after you check if the bound has been reached outside the synchronized block, when entering the synchronized block the value can already be changed by another thread. So you need to do a recheck inside the synchronized block OR to first synchronize on the shared lock(**counterObj**) before the check and increment.

```
        while (true) {
            synchronized (counterObj) {
                if (counterObj.get() < bound)
                    counterObj.incrementAndGet();
                else break;
            }
        }
```

Note that the **AtomicInteger** class synchronized methods aren't helping now, but because it is a mutable object, it helps to use it as a shared lock. If you used an **Integer** instead, being immutable, a new instance will have been created when you incremented it. So now, it's only function is a wrapper holding the integer result.

Putting it all together:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        try {
            app.launch();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void launch() throws InterruptedException {
        int increments = 100;
        AtomicInteger counterObj = new AtomicInteger(0);
        CounterThread th1 = new CounterThread("1", counterObj, increments);
        CounterThread th2 = new CounterThread("2", counterObj, increments);
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th1.waitFinish();
        th2.waitFinish();

        System.out.println(counterObj.get());
    }
}

public class CounterThread implements Runnable {
    private final String threadID;
    private AtomicInteger counterObj;
    private int bound;
    private Thread thread;

    public CounterThread(String threadID, AtomicInteger counter, int bound) {
        this.threadID = threadID;
        this.counterObj = counter;
        this.bound = bound;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (counterObj) {
                if (counterObj.get() < bound)
                    counterObj.incrementAndGet();
                else break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadID + " finished");
    }


    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        thread = new Thread(this, threadID);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void waitFinish() throws InterruptedException {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```